# Estimate market positioning from flow data

Tags: estimation, sampling

I have a set of time series data from a bank that is transaction data from all its clients on a particular currency.

From that data, I attempt to estimate the current "position" of all market participants in that currency.

I do that through a rolling 20 day total (1 month). However sometimes that total changes significantly due to a large data point dropping out of the rolling window, which is an issue in creating an estimate of "positioning".

My questions are

1. Is estimating the positioning from flow data reasonable?
2. how to adjust for rolling sum changing significantly not due to new data, but old data dropping out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your second point, use an exponential moving average rather than a simple moving average, or more technically, use an [infinite impulse response filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response) rather than a [finite impulse response filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response).

This will avoid the drastic dropping out of older data.